# Angular 2 Modelbinding to simpletype (string) not working

Tags: types, typescript, angular, model-binding

I've a simple component with a input for a string field:

```
import {Component, Input} from 'angular2/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'mundo-input',
    template: `
        <input class="form-control"  [(ngModel)]="zeit"  />
    `
})
export class MundoInputComponent  {
    @Input() zeit: string;    
}
```

I am consuming this component like this:

```
<mundo-input [(zeit)]="myzeit"></mundo-input>
```

The myzeit-property from the outer component gets injected correctly. When I change the value by hand and press save on the outside component, the myzeit-property has the old value.

I changed the type of zeit from string to a Hero class (like in the NG2 Tutorial) and changed the binding of the input to zeit.name. The two-way databinding worked.

Is it possible to bind to a property of type string from the outer component? Or is it just possible with complex types (classes)?

Comment: What's the difference to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36320605/angular-2-component-modelbinding-is-not-working/36338106#36338106 ?

Comment: I first edited the question you linked, but rolled back because it's a different question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add an ouput to your component to be able to leverage two-way binding:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'mundo-input',
  template: `
    <input class="form-control" [ngModel]="zeit"
               (ngModelChange)="onChange($event)" />
  `
})
export class MundoInputComponent  {
  @Input() zeit: string;    
  @Output() zeitChange:EventEmitter<string> = new EventEmitter();

  onChange(val) {
    this.zeitChange.emit(val);
  }
}
```

By convention the output must have the `zeitChange` to be able to use the shortcut `[(zeit)]="myzeit"`:

```
<mundo-input [(zeit)]="myzeit"></mundo-input>
```

In your case you only use one-way binding for the `zeit` parameter.

See this plunkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/snaM4y?p=preview.

Comment: that makes sense, but it's still not working. Why do I need an output for a simple type, but classes are working without output?

Comment: With primitive type you can't work by reference for updates within the sub component...

Comment: Awesome man, I forgot the to put zeit in brackets like <mundo-input [(zeit)]="myzeit"></mundo-input> Thank you very much!